# How to bind local variable respecting DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

ive a little problem with WPF. I hope i can explain my problem well and it will not be confusing too much.

Using multiple Views i have a property which stores the "Active" View.

Classic_View_Model : View_Base

Modern_View_Model : View_Base

Property:

```
private View_Base activeView;
    public View_Base ActiveView
    {
        get { return activeView; }
        set
        {
            this.activeView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(PropertyExtensions.GetPropertyName(() => ActiveView));
        }
    }
```

Cause each of my views should be displayed different i also have multiple DataTemplates.

DataTemplates:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ClassicViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type views:Classic_View}">
        <views:Classic_View DataContext="{Binding ClassicView}" ></views:Classic_View>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ModernViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type views:Modern_View}">
        <views:Modern_View DataContext="{Binding ModernView}" ></views:Modern_View>
    </DataTemplate>
```

My Problem is, that i dont know how i can display one property respecting the DataType dynamicaly. Before ive just used it with Collections in an ItemsControl.

Ive already tried to use an ItemsControl and bind the property as ItemsSource but it dosent work.

Is there any way to display an element based on the DataType of my property where the source is NOT a collection?

Dosent work:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveView}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Which one property you are talking about ? Your question is unclear. You are already using DataTemplates for diff DataTypes.

Comment: _"Is there any way to display an element based on the DataType of my property where the source is NOT a collection?"_ -- sure, the `ContentControl` will display a single item based on its `DataTemplate`. Unfortunately, your question is not clear. The title implies you want to bind to a local variable, which is not possible at all. The rest of the post seems to ask something different, but I'm not sure what. Please provide a [mcve] that shows clearly what you're doing, with a precise explanation of what the code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: Lets try it again:

I have a variable "ClassicView", a variable "ModernView" and a variable "ActiveView".
ActiveView ist typeof the base type "Base_View".
I want to achive, that i can display my "ActiveView".
Based of the type stored into (ClassicView or ModernView) i want to display different UserControls.

Maybe im making something wrong but ContentControl also dosent work
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ActiveView}"></ContentControl>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i got the solution myself.

Whats needed is an ContentTemplateSelector which takes care of the differncing.

```
public class ViewSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            if (item is Views.Classic_View_Model)
                return (container as FrameworkElement).FindResource("ClassicViewTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            else if (item is Views.Modern_View_Model)
                return (container as FrameworkElement).FindResource("ModernViewTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Then create a local instance of the DataTemplateSelector:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <local:ViewSelector x:Key="viewSelector"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

The ContentControl should then look like following:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ActiveView}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource viewSelector}"></ContentControl>
```

To make the binding work, i also had to modify my DataTemplates and bind to the "ActiveView" set in the ContentControl:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ClassicViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type views:Classic_View_Model}">
            <views:Classic_View DataContext="{Binding}" ></views:Classic_View>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ModernViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type views:Modern_View_Model}">
            <views:Modern_View DataContext="{Binding}" ></views:Modern_View>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: A `DataTemplateSelector` that makes its decision based solely on the types of the item being presented is bizarre, given that the `DataTemplate` on its own can accomplish that.

Comment: Maybe you can show me how the Control has to look like to make it work without the DataTemplateSelector. I have the DataTemplates and a variable, where objects of different types can be stored. I want to have an element which uses the DataTemplate based on the type.